# Vanilla JS plugin template

Tags: javascript

Okay, we all know how to write jQuery plugins: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Can someone advise on a *pure Javascript* template plugin with methods and default settings?

I want to make it work with a single node and with a node array (`querySelectorAll`)

Something like this:

```
var PluginName = function(selector){
    ...
}
```

And call it like this:

```
var dropdown = new PluginName('.dropdown');
```

And be able to close all dropdowns like this:

```
dropdown.close();
```

Comment: Pure Javascript doesn't have `selectors`, that's a feature of jQuery. You'll need to pass DOM nodes. Is that acceptable?

Comment: we can use `querySelector`

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that querySelector isn't available in some older browsers: http://caniuse.com/queryselector

Comment: yes, but i care only of modern browsers. that's why i try to drop jQuery.

Comment: jQuery is for a lot more than just old browsers. jQuery is for making development easy. In my eyes, the only reason to drop it is if you are creating some sort of javascript API toolkit which other developers are adding to their site, kind of look Google Maps because then dealing with jQuery conflicts can be troublesome.

Comment: @Nucleon I'm doing just that. I wouldn't be surprised if others are as well.

Comment: You can feature test for querySelector support before invoking your script. [See here](http://gomakethings.com/ditching-jquery-for-vanilla-js/). If you're using modern ES5 APIs, so many of the things you use jQuery for are just as "easy" in pure, native JS, with much better performance.

Answer (score 21):

I've been using module patterns with inits and public methods for a little while now. Not an exact match-for-match of the jQuery plugin pattern, but quite extensible and works really well. Just recently updated it for UMD/CommonJS/AMD/etc.

You checkout [my starter template here](https://gist.github.com/cferdinandi/ece94569aefcffa5f7fa), and view a [working example here](https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll).

For good measure, the full template here:

```
/**
 *
 * Name v0.0.1
 * Description, by Chris Ferdinandi.
 * http://gomakethings.com
 *
 * Free to use under the MIT License.
 * http://gomakethings.com/mit/
 *
 */

(function (root, factory) {
    if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
        define(factory);
    } else if ( typeof exports === 'object' ) {
        module.exports = factory;
    } else {
        root.Plugin = factory(root); // @todo Update to plugin name
    }
})(this, function (root) {

    'use strict';

    //
    // Variables
    //

    var exports = {}; // Object for public APIs
    var supports = !!document.querySelector && !!root.addEventListener; // Feature test

    // Default settings
    var defaults = {
        someVar: 123,
        callbackBefore: function () {},
        callbackAfter: function () {}
    };


    //
    // Methods
    //

    /**
     * Merge defaults with user options
     * @private
     * @param {Object} defaults Default settings
     * @param {Object} options User options
     * @returns {Object} Merged values of defaults and options
     */
    var extend = function ( defaults, options ) {
        for ( var key in options ) {
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(options, key)) {
                defaults[key] = options[key];
            }
        }
        return defaults;
    };

    /**
     * A simple forEach() implementation for Arrays, Objects and NodeLists
     * @private
     * @param {Array|Object|NodeList} collection Collection of items to iterate
     * @param {Function} callback Callback function for each iteration
     * @param {Array|Object|NodeList} scope Object/NodeList/Array that forEach is iterating over (aka `this`)
     */
    var forEach = function (collection, callback, scope) {
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(collection) === '[object Object]') {
            for (var prop in collection) {
                if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(collection, prop)) {
                    callback.call(scope, collection[prop], prop, collection);
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (var i = 0, len = collection.length; i < len; i++) {
                callback.call(scope, collection[i], i, collection);
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * Remove whitespace from a string
     * @private
     * @param {String} string
     * @returns {String}
     */
    var trim = function ( string ) {
        return string.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    };

    /**
     * Convert data-options attribute into an object of key/value pairs
     * @private
     * @param {String} options Link-specific options as a data attribute string
     * @returns {Object}
     */
    var getDataOptions = function ( options ) {
        var settings = {};
        // Create a key/value pair for each setting
        if ( options ) {
            options = options.split(';');
            options.forEach( function(option) {
                option = trim(option);
                if ( option !== '' ) {
                    option = option.split(':');
                    settings[option[0]] = trim(option[1]);
                }
            });
        }
        return settings;
    };

    // @todo Do something...

    /**
     * Initialize Plugin
     * @public
     * @param {Object} options User settings
     */
    exports.init = function ( options ) {

        // feature test
        if ( !supports ) return;

        // @todo Do something...

    };


    //
    // Public APIs
    //

    return exports;

});
```

Answer (score 9):

I would say that you want a JavaScript class.

```
var PluginName = function(selector){
    // Constructor here
    this.el = document.querySelector(selector);
}

PluginName.prototype.close = function(){
    console.log(this.el);
}

PluginName.prototype.anotherMethod = function(){
    console.log(this.el);
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var dropdown = new PluginName('.dropdown');
dropdown.close();
dropdown.anotherMethod();
```

One common practice to plugins is to pass an options object in the constructor. This way you can parameterize some behaviour elegantly. Example:

```
var dropdown = new PluginName({el:'.dropdown',slideInterval:1000, effect:'fade'});
```

Answer (score 4):

Look up javascript prototypal inheritance.

```
function PluginName(selector) {
    this.node = document.querySelector(selector);
        if (this.node == null) {
            // whoops node not found! Handle Error
        }

    return this;
}

PluginName.prototype.close = function() {
        this.var = "blah";
        // do stuff
}

var myPlugin = new Plugin(".selector")
```

Also this site has awesome javascript design patterns - http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/